# Exception Handler cannot be resolved using JAVA In Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, exception

I am newbie in android. I have used this code in my project but this is giving me error at this line    `ExceptionHandler.logException(e);`  and there is Error :

**ExceptionHandler cannot be resolved**

```
catch (JSONException e) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.ExceptionGeneral);
            ExceptionHandler.logException(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have already imported these references. What other references I need to import Please mention.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONException;
```

Comment: if u want to print the exception log use Log.d("exception",e.toString);

Answer (score 1):

There is no ExceptionHandler class in Android, use [Log](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).

Answer (score 1):

like Marton said, you need to use Log. Log can basically be used to debug in the same way that you use "System.out.print("String")" in Java. So, you can have the Log class send messages to a view called LogCat within Android (you usually have to open this view yourself).

The way log works is like this:

```
Log.v("Testing", "Show me this message");
```

Where 'v' is the type of Log message (there are a couple) and "Testing" is the tag you would like to associate it. Tags are useful because you can filter by tags, so you could, for example, have LogCat temporarily only display Logs with the tag Testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use all the classes in Java while working in Android platform. Google has chosen Java as a language for development in Android. Usage of `ExceptionHandler` is not allowed in android. Please refer the [packages list](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) allowed in android development. You can use    `android.util.Log` for logging in android applications